# Wordpress WooCommerce 'woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta' filter hook not being triggered

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filter, hook

I've got the hook set up for 'woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta' but it is not being triggered during a purchase. My code is below. Note, the code is simplified with the function simply logging a message so I can see if it is being triggered.

```
function filter_woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta( $array ) { 
    error_log("GOT TO filter_woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta()");
    return $array; 
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta', 'filter_woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta', 10, 1 );
```

I have configured many other WooCommerce hooks and they are being triggered correctly. Is there something special about 'woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta'? Does something have to be configured elsewhere before this hook is triggered?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Cheers!!

Comment: If you are trying to hide meta data from forntend, why don't you name your metadata name starting with _. Something like `_itemmeta_name`. This will hide the data. Tried this method?

Comment: Shouldn't the 'woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta' hook that I entered be triggered? I am trying to hide meta data and can try the underscore before the metadata name, but I'm very curious to know why the code I suggested is not triggered. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem recently. Still trying to figure out what's going on, but I can sure you that, if you put this code at *functions.php* of theme, there's a great chance to get this specific hook to work.

However, this problem affects not only *woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta* hooks, but other ones like *woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta*, and probably everything suffixed by *_order_itemmeta* (only a personal guess in this last part)

Obs: Before trying this workaround above, certify yourself that you're using this hook on Order Details Metabox. I think this is the only place where these hooks like **_order_itemmeta* are supposed to get work, anyway.